# How do I prevent the members of a compound view from restoring their inidividual states?

Tags: android, view

I have a custom ViewGroup object which is composed of two spinners (whose values are interdependent), and whose layout is defined in an XML file. I want this compound view object to be able to restore its own state upon orientation changes. The problem is that even though I have overridden `onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state)` in the custom view object code, and I can see that this code does appear to correctly restore the object state when I step through the code, after I restore my custom ViewGroup state the individual Spinners seem to restore themselves erraneously over the top of my custom restore.

This would be fine if they did so correctly, but it seems that the system stores instance states for the Spinners by id, and since there are multiple instances of my compound view, it saves the state of one of them and restores it back to all of them. How can I tell the Spinners that my compound view holds to not restore themselves? Subclassing Spinner with an empty onRestoreInstanceState method didn't work because Spinner throws a runtime exception if you fail to call Spinner.onRestoreInstanceState from the dummy subclass method.